# Summation of fields in SQL Query or getting results and then looping in code?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have more than **100K rows in my table**. I want to get the sum of data with where condition on non-indexed field (Received data would be 50-100 rows). What should I prefer? SQL Sum or get the filtered data and sum the data using loop.

A table 'BOOKS' have 15 number-columns like 'Maths', 'English', 'History' and so on that stores the count of the books ordered by customer. I want to get the data of how many books of each subject customer ordered in a year depending on customer card number (this field is not indexed).

**Option 1**

```
query = 'SELECT SUM('subject_1) as qunatity_1, SUM(subject_2) as quantity_2....SUM(subject_15) as quantity_15 from BOOKS where customer_card_no=10'
```

Should I just hit this query and get the required data

**Option 2**

```
query = 'SELECT subject_1, subject_2...subject_15 from BOOKS where customer_card_no=10'
```

loop on the received rows and sum the fields to get required data

Comment: Why would you even consider option 2? Is there something you aren't telling us? (actually there's a lot you aren't telling us) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: I am not sure which option would get the data faster, as number of rows would keep increasing.
Also what if the field on which I am filtering is not the indexed field?

Comment: The main question is what result do you want?

Comment: So your options are acquire 1 row over the network or lots of rows , have the server do the hard work or your app..

Comment: Yes, so acquire 1 row with all summation of each subject or get all rows with customer_card_no and then sum the data at code level

Comment: Where would you guess is most likely to bottleneck?

Comment: I guess filtering on non-indexed field would already slower the query when no of rows would increase, and summation in the same query would add more time to the query